# sitemap settings in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

i have activated the sitemap feature in my site collection, but i faced a problem in the generated xml sitemap in the URL format:-

172.16.30.9:4040/sitemap0.xml


//172.16.30.9:4040/sitemap_mobile0.xml


and the same for inner files as below:-

//172.16.30.9:4040/en/PoliticalStudies/Pages/The-2017-Korean-Missile-Crisis-.aspx

2017-08-22T09:37:00Z



//172.16.30.9:4040/en/News/Pages/Yemeni_Public_Opinion_Attitudes_towards_the_National_Dialogue_Document_and_the_Second_Transitional_Phase.aspx

2017-07-28T18:53:11Z


my questions is:-

1- how i can change the IP of the loc to be the domain name ?

2- what is the value of mobile xml since i have a responsive web site? how i can remove it ?

3- all generated links in the sitemap is for English "en" pages, where is my other variate pages, taking into consideration the pages are published and approved ??